# shape does not appear on screen while adding vertices dynamically

Tags: android

I have a serious problem in my renderer class of opengl
this is my Renderer class for drawing shapes on glsurfaceview.
I am completely new in OpenGl.

```
package com.view9.stoddart.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlPointObject;
import com.view9.stoddart.model.OpenGlRoofObject;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class StoddartRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private Context mContext;
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer = null;
    private ShortBuffer mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer = null;
    private int mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices = 0;

    public float mAngleX = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleY = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleZ = 0.0f;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;
    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.6f;
    int pointers = 0;
    float distance = 1;
    RenderListener renderListener;
    private OpenGlRoofObject roofObject;

    public void setRenderListener(RenderListener renderListener) {
        this.renderListener = renderListener;
    }


    public StoddartRenderer(Context context, OpenGlRoofObject roofObject) {
        mContext = context;
        this.roofObject = roofObject;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleZ, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

        // Set line color to black
        gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Draw all lines
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Get all the buffers ready
        setAllBuffers();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (height == 0) height = 1;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float aspect = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
//        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    private void setAllBuffers() {
        ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> cordinateList = new ArrayList<>();


        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        for (int pointCount = 0; pointCount < roofObject.getPoinstList().size(); pointCount++) {
            OpenGlPointObject pointObject = roofObject.getPoinstList().get(pointCount);
            cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(pointObject.getxAsis()/10000, pointObject.getyAxis()/10000, pointObject.getzAxis()/10000));
        }


        List<Float> vList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cordinateList.size(); i++) {
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getxAxis());
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getyAxis());
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getzAxis());
        }

        float[] vertexlist = new float[vList.size()];
        int count = 0;
        for (Float f : vList) {
            vertexlist[count++] = f;
        }

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexlist.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        // Set triangle border buffer with vertex indices
        short trigborderindexlist[] = {
                89, 78,
                79, 89,
                78, 81,
                90, 86,
                83, 82,
                88, 83,
                92, 79,
                87, 78,
                79, 85,
                91, 80,
                90, 84,
                89, 80,
                88, 84,
                83, 84,
                82, 87,
                80, 84,
                86, 88,
                87, 92,
                81, 85,
                91, 90,
                92, 91,
                98, 97,
                93, 98,
                94, 93,
                95, 94,
                96, 95,
                97, 96


        };
        mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices = trigborderindexlist.length;
        ByteBuffer tbibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(trigborderindexlist.length * 2);
        tbibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer = tbibb.asShortBuffer();
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer.put(trigborderindexlist);
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;
                mAngleY = (mAngleY + (int) (dx * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR) + 360) % 360;
                mAngleX = (mAngleX + (int) (dy * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR) + 360) % 360;
                break;

        }
        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }


    protected final float fingerDist(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }


}
```

It doesnot work is there any thing I am missing ? In my xml api I get points in string format so I need to parse it to float **pointObject** carries three datas all in float.Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.Please save my life I've wasted my two hole day for making some logic but was not worth.

Comment: guys if u down vote then You must give the reason why you down voted .

Comment: Does it work, if you add some static coordinates programmatically?

Comment: I dont get u ? I am completely new in opengl.I hope you know what my problem is .

Comment: I used for loop to add float type co-ordinates to the list and again converting to array, but it does not give me any shapes :(

Comment: Well, if using floats directly doesn't work either, the conversion from string to float cannot be the problem -- so you should probably change the name of your question.

Comment: m I missing any code or is there any thing going wrong with this approach ?

Comment: I cannot help you any further in regards of OpenGL. It's just, that it is not the string to float conversion that is your problem, so you might want to change the title of the question.

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, but I understand why somebody might have. You say that your code "does not work", but you never explain what exactly the problem is. You generally need a much more precise problem description to get help. Describe what you're expecting, what actually happens, and where exactly the problem is. Also, try to simplify and shorten the code as much as possible. I doubt that all of this is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved my problem.There was simple mistake in xml parsing and adding data to the z-axis. :) any way Thanks to all of you for showing your kindness